# VBA - Regular expression

Tags: regex, vba

I've a string like this:

```
123 45-ABC 12 345 DEF
123 45-ABC 1345 DEF
123 45-ABC 345 DEF
```

I'm trying to pattern match these with regular expression. I've tried the following:

```
<[0-9 ]{4;6}-[A-Z]{3} [0-9]{3;5} DEF
<[0-9 ]{4;6}-[A-Z]{3} [0-9 ]{3;6} DEF
<[0-9 ]{4;6}-[A-Z]{3} [0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{1;3} DEF
<[0-9 ]{4;6}-[A-Z]{3} [0-9]{2}[ \r\t\n\f]?[0-9]{1;3} DEF
```

But none of them are working for me...

Any tips?

Comment: I'm fairly new to regex, but you could give this a try: `\d{3}\s\d{2}\-[A-Z]{3}\s\d*\s?\d*\s[A-Z]{3}` I feel like it could be shortened a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: "\b\d*\s*\d*-[A-Z]*\s*[\d ]*\b\s*[A-Z]*\b"

You can test it here: http://rubular.com/r/UkvvrJ6tGL

You may want to change all "\d" with "[0-9]" and "[A-Z]" to "[a-zA-Z]". You may also want to change all " * " with "{3}" or "{2,3}", etc (except in " \s* "), if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim ResultString As String
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
Dim myRegExp As RegExp
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "\d{3}[ ]\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}[ ]\d+(?:[ ]\d+)?[ ][A-Z]+"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(SubjectString)
If myMatches.Count >= 1 Then
    ResultString = myMatches(0).Value
Else
    ResultString = ""
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddly due to the lack of zero-or-once and Office's oddball syntax, try:

```
<[0-9 ]{4,6}-[A-Z]{3}[0-9 ]{3,8}DEF>
```